# I want to get carrier's name and code from mobile number in php

Tags: php

I need to get carrier's code from given number in php. For example if phone number is of "Globacom Ltd" then I should be able to get carrier code "GLO".  How to do it ? I checked clickatell.com but I could not find any such API.

Comment: Is there any php professional who can resolve this issue ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got a solutions from twilio api.